# How can I change from Blood to Tears? (Repentance / Reversal achievement)

Tags: achievements, might-and-magic-heroes-6

So after many months of battles, I've finally accrued the 1,000 blood reputation needed to reach Blood level 2. At the moment, however, I'm at Tears Level 1, and it is not obvious to me how one goes about swapping one for the other.

I know this is possible because there are achievements awarded for it, I'm just a little confused as to how...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change from Tears to Blood (or vice versa) in the campaign, because your tears/blood path has pretty important ramifications, changing parts of the map entirely.

As such, Blood / Tears switching is limited to multiplayer games only.